# Is there a function similar to awsglue's getResolvedOptions that will work in an azure databricks notebook using python?

Tags: python, databricks, aws-glue, azure-databricks

I'm moving code into azure and am wondering what function would be used to accomplish the same thing in python, but without awsglue:

```
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', 'day_partition_key'])
print(args['day_partition_key'])
```

Answer (score 0):

In Databricks, if you're using Notebook for data processing, then you can pass parameters to a job when creating it as described in [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/jobs.html#create-a-job) (step 6), and then access these parameters via [widgets](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html), for example, if you need to pass parameter, then you declare it as widget with name `param1`:

```py
dbutils.widgets.text("param1", "default_value", "Description")
```

and extract the value with:

```py
param1 = dbutils.widgets.get("param1")
```

and declare the same parameter when creating the job.

If you're using Python or Jar job, then you receive parameters as usual, from command-line.